# lining up/ordering values in columns based on the pattern on the first part of the values

Tags: r, bash, dataframe, sorting

I have the following tab delimited  [file](https://filebin.net/zl6vjs6awo0pfoi1)

As you will see, all values (except the ones in the beginning of each line/row) have the following format XXX_YYYYYYYY_k??7_ZZZZZZ_W where XXX is a three digit number with values from 0 to 588, YYYYYYYY is a reference that can either be a fivedigit number or a combination of letters+numbers, k??7 can be either k127 or k117 and the remaining ones are also numbers.

Thus each line of the table looks like this:

`OG0000302  0_35175_T538DRAFT_00081 1_51617_IE52DRAFT_02642 2_52817_IE58DRAFT_01675 3_66383_Ga0066898_11773 4_66389_Ga0066897_101939    5_80188_Ga0105816_11954 6_80461_Ga0105827_11324 7_80519_Ga0105824_100891    8_ERR3393546_k127_69708_30  9_ERR3393546_k127_581877_18 10_ERR3393546_k127_120839_3 11_ERR3393546_k127_33683_4  12_ERR3393547_k127_525856_12    13_ERR3393550_k127_1276550_5    14_ERR3393550_k127_269209_9 15_ERR3393550_k127_298528_2 16_ERR3393551_k127_65255_57 17_ERR3393551_k127_716061_116   18_ERR3393552_k127_248675_58    19_ERR3393552_k127_189938_18    20_ERR3393553_k127_125251_17    ...`

It is not evident from the example I put above but not all lines have the same length because some values are missing. Here is an example towards the end of the first line:

```
581_SRR9699915_k127_307534_116  582_SRR9699917_k127_151371_1, SRR9699917_k127_261977_2, SRR9699917_k127_27181_6 583_SRR9699917_k127_349035_4    584_SRR9699917_k127_24084_7
```

As you can see the 583_sth_sth entry is missing! And here is what I am looking for:
I am looking for a solution that will align all columns based on the XXX number before the first underscore and whenever this number is missing there can be a space, a '0' or anything else that signifies that this field is missing. Therefore in the new/transformed table all values starting with 583 would be in the same column, all values starting with 584 would be in the same column, all values starting with 84 would be in the same column, etc etc (for all 589 fiels; 0-588)

PS: one more thing: in the example above the `"582_SRR9699917_k127_151371_1, SRR9699917_k127_261977_2, SRR9699917_k127_27181_6"` is not a typo. Simply some fields have multiple entries seperated by commas - but that should not be a problem, it is only the first entry that matters and therefore has also the XXX number!

I dont know if this is easier in bash or R, I would be happy with any approach that can make sense of these data! :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would be looking at extracting numbers with `stringr::str_extract` inside `dplyr::mutate` (subsequently converted via `as.numeric`), then making a `myTib <- tibble(num = 1:588)` and doing something like `left_join(myTib, data, by = "num")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With {tidyverse}, try:

```
library(tidyvese)

df <- read_tsv("newly_repaired", col_names = FALSE)

df_wrangled <- 
  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = !X1, names_to = "names", values_to = "values") %>% 
  select(-names) %>% 
  mutate(code = str_extract(values, "^\\d+(?=_)")) %>% 
  replace_na(list(code = "xxx")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = code, values_from = values) %>%
  select(c(X1, xxx, c(seq(1, ncol(.)-3, 1) %>% as.character()))) # Making sure the `xxx` column with NA is at the second position, and the other columns are in descending order.

## Ramdom sample as an example of results:
df_wrangled %>% select(1:4, 100) %>% sample_n(5) %>%  as.data.frame()

         X1                                                            xxx                       1                           98
1 OG0000536                                                 NA, NA, NA, NA 1_51617_IE52DRAFT_04699 98_ERR4398751_k127_499284_40
2 OG0000421                                         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA 1_51617_IE52DRAFT_02586   98_ERR4398751_k127_7322_13
3 OG0000372                                                         NA, NA 1_51617_IE52DRAFT_02902  98_ERR4398751_k127_150230_5
4 OG0000634 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA 1_51617_IE52DRAFT_01016 98_ERR4398751_k127_162422_19
5 OG0000457                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA 1_51617_IE52DRAFT_01614 98_ERR4398751_k127_182210_78
```

Comment: Hey! That is great! I have one quick question though: at the end of the file (last 4-5 columns) it creates a long string of NAs and all the 440_ values are spread among them - cant really see why this is happening and it is not a big deal; I can totally live with one column acting out so its still ok and the script works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: In my df_wrangled I do see that the column "440" is at the very end, but the NA's should be stored in the "xxx" column. I will update the answer to make it more manegeable.